# How to put sequence number in first column in bootgrid table with php server side

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, server-side, jquery-bootgrid

I tried to practice examples on [Bootgrid Command Buttons](http://www.jquery-bootgrid.com/Examples#command-buttons), but I am having trouble when putting sequence number in the first column. Please help me. thank you.

```
<table id="bootgrid" class="table table-bordered">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Number ?? </th>
        <th data-column-id="barcode" data-type="numeric">Barcode</th>
        <th data-column-id="name_equipment">Name Eqp</th>
        <th data-column-id="commands" data-formatter="commands" data-sortable="false">Action</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var grid = $("#bootgrid").bootgrid({
    ajax: true,
    post: function ()
    {
        return {
            id: "b0df282a-0d67-40e5-8558-c9e93b7befed"
        };
    },
    url: "response.php",
    formatters: {
        "commands": function (column, row)
        {
            return "<a href=\"edit&code=" + row.barcode + "\" class=\"btn btn-xs btn-warning\"><span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-pencil\"></span></a> ";
        }
    }
}).on("loaded.rs.jquery.bootgrid", function () {});
$("#clearSearch").on("click", function ()
{
    $("#bootgrid").bootgrid("search");
});
```